# How can I run continuous Logcat in the background?

Tags: logging

I want to run a continuous logcat in the background to capture everything happening on my phone.

This needs to be written to disk line by line without delay. I want to capture the cause of random reboots.

Comment: Open a command line and issue `logcat -f /path/where/to/save/the/log`. The logcat tool will continue recording everything until you kill the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need root for this (where I was making mistakes).

So, in a terminal:

`su`

`logcat V > /sdcard/logcat.txt`

then, without killing the command, just press home to keep the terminal running in the background.

- V means verbose (the highest level of detail)
- D means debug

and there are other less detailed levels.

Exercise caution when sharing D and V level logs; they contain highly sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
adb -e logcat > log_file_name.txt
```